# 'pip install recommenders' is not working properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I'm running Jupyter notebook with pip 23.2.1 and Python 3.11.2.

Upon trying to run `pip install recommenders`, I get the following error:

`ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.6.0 Requires-Python >=3.6, <=3.8; 0.7.0 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.8; 1.0.0 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.9; 1.1.0 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.10; 1.1.1 Requires-Python >=3.6, <3.10 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement recommenders (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for recommenders`

Furthermore, I've tried `pip install git+https://github.com/microsoft/recommenders.git` (https://github.com/recommenders-team/recommenders/issues/1519), which returns the error `this is not an issue with pip` and

`numpy.distutils is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result of the deprecation of distutils itself. It will be removed for Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present. It is recommended to use` setuptools < 60.0 `for those Python versions. For more details, see: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html`

Comment: Have you tried using a supported version of Python? Looking at the error message, it looks like they support 3.6 through 3.9.

Answer (score 1):

I read in your question body that every possible version of `recommenders` requires python <3.10.  You're trying to install it with python 3.11.

So I beg to differ on the question title.  `pip install` *is* working properly: it refuses to install an unsupported version.

You may try using `pyenv` to create a python environment with 3.10.  E.g. look here for a tutorial: https://duncanleung.com/set-up-python-pyenv-virtualenv-poetry/.